# Computação Paralela - comunicação entre threads

Tags: stack, paralelismo

Essa é uma duvida que me surgiu quando eu estava tentando resolver um problema em um cliente, o problema acabou sendo outra coisa mas a duvida continuou.

Imagine uma situação onde existem dois programas, *prog1* e *prog2*, onde se utiliza uma `dll` fazendo com que quando o *prog1* dispara um evento o *prog2* recebe esse evento e o gestiona.

Exemplo:

*prog1* executa um estabelecimento de chamada

*prog2* executa `OnEstabelecimentoDeChamada`

Uma vez que estão sendo executados de modo assíncrono e neste ponto há uma comunicação entre os dois e como argumento dessa chamada o *prog1* passa um objeto para *prog2*. A pergunta é, como fica a pilha de execução de ambos os programas? O que acontece se um outro evento é chamado em *prog1* enquanto *prog2* ainda está executando o `OnEstabelecimentoDeChamada`?

Tentei ser o mais claro possível, gostaria de saber como ficam as chamadas propriamente na pilha de execução

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente quando sistemas se comunicam esse procedimento é feito em seguimentos de execução separados, ou seja, tanto o processo de estabelecer comunicação como os métodos propriamente ditos de troca de mensagens são executados em threads separadas. Isso porque no cenário em que ocorra uma indisponibilidade de uma das partes nenhum dos programas ficaria "preso" a falha de comunicação.

Então, isso significa que uma pilha de execução em separado do stack de chamadas principal do programa deve ser usada para manter a comunicação e disponibilidade das outras funcionalidades nos dois sistemas.